# Understanding state input in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, state

I have a method `submitMessage` that is supposed to concatenate the current message that has been stored in my input state and then clear it:

```
submitMessage() {
  this.setState({
    input: '',
    messages : [...this.state.messages, this.state.input]
  });
}
```

The method is working as intended and the whole app too, what I don't understand is why input can be cleared before the concatenate, is input and `this.state.input` not in the same place in memory ?

Here is my full code:

```
class DisplayMessages extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      input: '',
      messages: []
    }    
  }
  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      input: event.target.value,
      messages: this.state.messages
      })
  }
  submitMessage() {
    this.setState({
      input: '',
    messages : [...this.state.messages, this.state.input]
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Type in a new Message:</h2>
        <input onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} value={this.state.input} />
        <button onClick={this.submitMessage.bind(this)}>Submit</button>
        <ul>{this.state.messages.map((item) => {
            return <li key={item + 1}>{item}</li>
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: `input` is an html DOM element, the other, `this.state.input` is a javascript object, they are two completely different things. What do you mean by "...why `this.state.input` is not cleared before the concatenate"?

Comment: I fixed my question but I think you answered it,

Comment: when you say 
    *submitMessage() {
        this.setState({
          input: '',
        messages : [...this.state.messages, this.state.input]
        })*
, state change will be reflected on the next render. setting input to empty and then accessing it on new line will still give old state back. Thats how setState works.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see now. You ask how setting `input: ''` the line above `messages : [...this.state.messages, this.state.input]` works. In react, state and props are to be treated as immutable objects, and react state works between render cycles, all state updates within any single cycle are queued up and batch processed for the *next* render cycle.

Comment: @DrewReese thanks, It answered my question, can you repost it as an answer so I can validate you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why are `<input />` and `this.state.input` not in the same place in memory?

`input` is an html DOM element, while the other, `this.state.input` is a javascript object, they are two completely different things. The only thing relating the two is the JSX syntax and react framework.

> Why can input be cleared before the message concatenation?

In react, state and props are treated as immutable objects, and react state works between render cycles. All state updates within any *single cycle* are queued up and batch processed for the next render cycle. Setting `this.state.input` to an empty string *and* appending it to the `this.state.messages` array are queued to to be processed for *the next* rendered view.

The following are all equivalent in terms of next computed state:

```
this.setState({
  input: '',
  messages: [...this.state.messages, this.state.input],
});
```

and

```
this.setState({
  messages: [...this.state.messages, this.state.input],
  input: '',
});
```

and

```
this.setState({ input: '' });
this.setState({
  messages: [...this.state.messages, this.state.input],
});
```

and even

```
this.setState({ input: '' });
this.setState({
  messages: [...this.state.messages, this.state.input],
});
this.setState({
  messages: [...this.state.messages, this.state.input],
});
```

The last one you may find surprising (*what!?*), but recall that state state is immutable and batch processed, so in the case of updating `messages`, `this.state.messages` ***and*** `this.state.input` have the same values in both calls, and thus, the last one invoked is what sets state. BTW, (and outside the scope of this question), functional state updates help solve the issue with this last example.